# How to convert password inputs to DOTS instead of the text

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a login page in my application but I would like to know how I can convert the user's password into dots so that when a user enters his or her credentials she can see her username but the password is in a doted formula. Can't seem to find an example on the net any zend related link will be also appreciated. Bare in mind I'm using a zend form.[image]

Comment: use input type="password"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For *[ZEND](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#password)*,

```
$password = new Element\Password('password');
$password
    ->setLabel('Password')
    ->setAttributes(array(
        'size'  => '30',
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm, but now I feel stupid should have known the is a zend element called password. Thank you

Comment: By the way. This could be found with a simple google search in the zend documentation! http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for `<input type="password" />`

```
<label><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" /></label>
```

Check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqHhh/)

Comment: Sorry should have added that im using a zend form

Comment: @Rikesh asnwer should works. Anyway, check **[Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html)**

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Zend-framework I hope this piece will work for you.

```
$password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
    $password->setLabel('Password')
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

And for HTML, you can use this piece of code

```
<label><input type="password" name="myPass" id="myPass" /></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.quickstart.html has everything 
you need. Please check it out